# Dividing layer with tracks by individual days in QGIS

Tags: qgis, point, csv, splitting, date

I have a CSV file that includes about 150 dates containing tracks for a particular bird. I successfully added it as a layer in QGIS.

My question is how can I divide all the dates into separate days?

Comment: Can you please show show a sample of your data? What kind of output would you like tot have and in which format? You can try the ["Split vector layer"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html#split-vector-layer)

Comment: Look at the "Split vector layer" processing tool : https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html#split-vector-layer

Comment: If this is a style issue, you can use a `categorized style`.

Comment: The data is from a GPS transmitter attached to the back of a bird. The data contains coordinates of the location, date and time of information collection, altitude and others.
The data is for about half a year and I want to visualize the bird's flight in QGIS day by day.
The data is in CSV format, attaching a link to Google Drive with a sample file with data for 3 days.
I will try "Split vector layer".

Comment: here is the link - https://drive.google.com/file/d/18GfZSjjfc-AjQtAvGu4PrVkK5RPhTlcl/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @NikolayYordanov: you can activate and configure on your layer the temporal controller, see here : https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/3/animating_time_series.html